Salesforce Marketing Could Emil Unique opens
Is there a way to download email performance reports to demonstrate audience who open our pervious email without using automation studio.
From the report, I am looking to know:

Audience Attribute = Email Addresses
Performance/tracking event = Opens
JobID = all campaigns
Time duration = past 6 months

Thank you.


Create a standard DataExtension with the fields you need to display in the report.
Create a scheduled automation with a SQL query that fills in the DataExtension.

Check the following link, as it can help you a lot in the development of your SQL query.
https://dataviews.io/
